# std::basic_stringstream<unsigned char> won't compile with MSVC 10

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, utf-8, stringstream

I'm trying to get UTF-8 chars to co-exist with ANSI 8-bit chars.  My strategy has been to represent utf-8 chars as `unsigned char` so that appropriate overloads of functions can be used for the two character types.

e.g.

```
    namespace MyStuff
    {
        typedef uchar utf8_t;
        typedef std::basic_string<utf8_t> U8string;
    }
    void SomeFunc(std::string &s);
    void SomeFunc(std::wstring &s);
    void SomeFunc(MyStuff::U8string &s);
```

This all works pretty well until I try to use a stringstream.

```
    std::basic_ostringstream<MyStuff::utf8_t> ostr;
    ostr << 1;
```

MSVC Visual C++ Express V10 won't compile this:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocmon(213): 
    warning C4273: 'id' : inconsistent dll linkage
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocnum(65) : 
            see previous definition of 
            'public: static std::locale::id std::numpunct<unsigned char>::id'
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocnum(65) : 
            while compiling class template static data member 'std::locale::id 
            std::numpunct<_Elem>::id'
    with
    [
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t
    ]
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocnum(1149) : 
        see reference to function template instantiation 
        'const _Facet &std::use_facet<std::numpunct<_Elem>>(const std::locale &)' 
        being compiled
    with
    [
        _Facet=std::numpunct<Tk::utf8_t>,
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t
    ]
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocnum(1143) : 
        while compiling class template member function 
        'std::ostreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits> 
        std::num_put<_Elem,_OutIt>::
        do_put(_OutIt,std::ios_base &,_Elem,std::_Bool) const'
    with
    [
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t,
        _Traits=std::char_traits<Tk::utf8_t>,
        _OutIt=std::ostreambuf_iterator<Tk::utf8_t,std::char_traits<Tk::utf8_t>>
    ]
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(295) : 
        see reference to class template instantiation 'std::num_put<_Elem,_OutIt>' 
        being compiled
    with
    [
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t,
        _OutIt=std::ostreambuf_iterator<Tk::utf8_t,std::char_traits<Tk::utf8_t>>
    ]
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(281) : 
        while compiling class template member function 
        'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &
        std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
    with
    [
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t,
        _Traits=std::char_traits<Tk::utf8_t>
    ]
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\sstream(526) : 
        see reference to class template instantiation 
        'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' being compiled
    with
    [
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t,
        _Traits=std::char_traits<Tk::utf8_t>
    ]
    c:\users\michael\dvl\tmp\console\console.cpp(23) : 
        see reference to class template instantiation 
        'std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' being compiled
    with
    [
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t,
        _Traits=std::char_traits<Tk::utf8_t>,
        _Alloc=std::allocator<uchar>
    ]
```

.

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocmon(213): 
    error C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id' : definition of dllimport 
    static data member not allowed
    with
    [
        _Elem=Tk::utf8_t
    ]
```

Any ideas?

**** Edited 19 June 2012 ****

OK, I've gotten closer to understanding this, but not how to solve it.

As we all know, static class variables get defined twice:

- once in the class definition and
- once outside the class definition which establishes storage space.

e.g.

```
    // in .h file
    class CFoo
    {
        // ...
        static int x;
    };

    // in .cpp file
    int CFoo::x = 42;
```

Now in the VC10 headers we get something like this:

```
    template<class _Elem>
    class numpunct : public locale::facet
    {
        // ...
        _CRTIMP2_PURE static locale::id id;
        // ...
    }
```

When the header is included in an application, `_CRTIMP2_PURE` is defined as `__declspec(dllimport)`, which means that the variable is imported from a dll.

Now the header also contains the following

```
    template<class _Elem>
    locale::id numpunct<_Elem>::id;
```

Note the absence of the `__declspec(dllimport)` qualifier.

i.e. The class declaration says that the static linkage of the `id` variable is in the dll, but for the general case, it gets declared outside the dll.

For the known cases, there are specialisations.

```
    template locale::id numpunct<char>::id;
    template locale::id numpunct<wchar_t>::id;
```

These are protected by `#if`s so that they are only included when building the DLL.  They are excluded otherwise.

i.e. *the `char` and `wchar_t` versions of numpunct ARE inside the dll*

So we have the class definition saying that id's storage is in the DLL, but that is only true for the `char` and `wchar_t` specialisations, meaning that my unsigned char version is doomed.  :-(

The only way forward that I can think of is to create my own specialisation: basically copying it from the header file and fixing it.  This raises many issues.

Anybody have a better idea?

Comment: I think basic problem here is that your strings of uchars are unknown type to C++, so it has no idea how to preform to-string and from-string conversions internally. Have you tried using only something like `ostr << uchar('a');`? Here is no problem as no conversion (like int->utf8_string) is required, only appending to the end of the internal string. I have no idea how to teach standard classes how to do it, but quick dig in C++ standard shold help at least a bit.

Comment: Note that also things like `ostr << "Something";` will not work (unless you explicitely define such operators of course), and it will probably make writing your program soooo much more painful.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/numpunct/ "Two standard specializations define the standard behavior for the char and wchar_t types." This probably means that you will have to provide your own specialization of this class, possibly also several other classes...

Comment: Basically, this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/ afaik. You've to provide the same for unsigned char. For details look at any library that does this for unicode.